# Trying to send notifications via Firebase using Cloud-Messaging API in my Android App

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase with my Android app to send notifications to my application using the cloud-messaging API. I am using a MYSQL database to store the token of the device using my application.

My issue is the token is not being inserted to the database once the user sends it the token. The insert field is blank when the user sends it so I'm assuming my PHP for this action is working and maybe it is something to do with my Android code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String urlInsertToken = "IP_ADDRESS_GOES_HERE/fcm_insert_token.php";
    Button btn;

    private static final String TAG = "MyFireActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =   getApplication().getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.FCM_PREF), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
           // SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
           // final String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
            //Log.d(TAG,"Token", + token);
            //Log.d(TAG," token" + token);
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,token,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            final String token = sharedPreferences.getString(getString(R.string.FCM_TOKEN), "");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,token,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,urlInsertToken,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {

                        }

                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            })

            {
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("fcm_token",token);
                    return params;
                }

            };

            MainActivity2.getMyInstance(MainActivity.this).addRequestQueue(stringRequest);

        }

    });
}
}
```

---

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
    require_once('db_connect.php');
    insertFCMToken();

}


/* 
Function used to insert Token from GCM
*/
function insertFCMToken(){

    global $conn;

    $fcm_token = $_POST["fcm_token"];


    $sql = "INSERT INTO fcm_info values ('".$fcm_token."');";



    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, please switch to retrofit2. Secondly storing the token in preferences is no longer relevant.You can get a hook to the fire base instance id service.

```
String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

I was once getting the exact error, mine fault was that the token was blank.

Also add echo in your php code, to verify the state of the token, sometimes volley behaves really unexpectedly for said reasons i switched to retrofit.alot faster.

retrofit internally uses the okhttp3 library therefore you can view the network log. With this you rectify whether or not the token was sent.

https://square.github.io/retrofit/